# Create a history trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I create 2 tables with postgresql:

```
afp
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('afp_id_seq'::regclass),
  perm_number character varying(90),
  type bigint,
  start_date character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT afp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

history_afp
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('history_afp_id_seq'::regclass),
  reason bigint,
  type bigint,
  ask_date character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT history_afp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I wanted to have an history trigger so when I will delete a row in `afp` the row will go in `history_afp`

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.before_update()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    SET SCHEMA 'public'
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.history_afp (
        type,
        ask_date
        )
    VALUES (
        OLD.type,
        OLD.start_date);
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$$; 

CREATE TRIGGER before_update_trigger
  BEFORE DELETE
  ON public.afp
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.before_update();
```

When I delete the row in table `afp`, it creates my new row in `history_afp` but it creates again the row in my table `afp`.

Someone have any idea why I have this error ?

Comment: Not that it matters for the error you got or even for execution, but properly names objects is important for consistency and *avoiding confusion*.   With that in mind I suggest trigger and function being Before_Update... is a poor naming choice for action taken on a delete operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

```
RETURN OLD;
```

rather than

```
RETURN NEW;
```

The problem is that `NEW` is undefined in delete triggers, and returning NULL will abort the deletion.